# Printing matrix line in Java

Tags: java, arrays, methods, 2d

I need to construct a method that receives a matrix as argument and prints its lines. For example, the method will receive the matrix below

```
int[][] matrix = {
    {3, 1, 2, 7, 2, 5, 6, 2},
    {2, 10, 20, 12, 13},
    {3, 7, 12, 15, 18, 4},
    {2, 11, 21, 12, 13}
};
```

And it must return

```
Line 0 : 3 1 2 7 2 5 6 2
Line 1 : 2 10 20 12 13
Line 2 : 3 7 12 15 18 4
Line 3 : 2 11 21 12 13
```

Here is the method:

```
public static void displayLines(int[][] matrix){    
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i){
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; ++j){ 
            System.out.print("Line nb " + i + " : " + matrix[i][j] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

But it does not print in the way I want. It prints like that and I'm trying to figure out how to solve it.

```
Line 0 : 3 
Line 0 : 1 
Line 0 : 2 
Line 0 : 7 
Line 0 : 2 
Line 0 : 5 
Line 0 : 6 
Line 0 : 2

// And so on for other lines
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `System.out.print` for each element of the array instead of each row of the array. Modify like this :

```
public static void displayLines(int[][] matrix){    
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i){
        System.out.print("Line " + i + " :"); // line header
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; ++j){ 
            System.out.print(" " + matrix[i][j]);
        }
        System.out.println(""); // end of line
    }
}
```

Note how an empty space is added before each element `" " + matrix[i][j]` to avoid trailing whitespace.

Also bear in mind you could write the second for loop like this

```
for (int n : matrix[i]) {
    System.out.print(" " + n);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about something like:

```
int rowNumber = 0;
for (int[] row : matrix){
    System.out.println("Line " + (rowNumber++) + " : " + Arrays.toString(row));
}
```

which will generate

```
Line 0 : [3, 1, 2, 7, 2, 5, 6, 2]
Line 1 : [2, 10, 20, 12, 13]
Line 2 : [3, 7, 12, 15, 18, 4]
Line 3 : [2, 11, 21, 12, 13]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the code below

```
public static void displayLines(int[][] matrix){    
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i){
        System.out.print("Line nb " + i + " : " );
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; ++j){ 
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void displayLines(int[][] matrix) {    
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
        System.out.print("Line " + i + " : ");
        for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; ++j) { 
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[][] matrix = { { 3, 1, 2, 7, 2, 5, 6, 2 }, { 2, 10, 20, 12, 13 },
        { 3, 7, 12, 15, 18, 4 }, { 2, 11, 21, 12, 13 } };
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; ++i) {
    System.out.print("Line " + i + " :");
    for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; ++j) {
        System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + "   ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```